# Motion with air resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile, drag

How to tackle real life problems in KINMEATICS in which air drag in some way is involved?

I've attached one such problem in which I was stuck.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you didn't notice that the enemy camps are right at the foot of cliff . Thus,in order to hit the camp,the catapult should at be at  a such a distance that by the time the projectile reaches the edge of cliff it's horizontal component of velocity becomes zero.

Because if there is even a small horizontal  component , the huge hight will ensure that the projectile lands far away from the target.

Comment: Sir, are you considering air drag in horizontal direction as well?Actually I used air drag only in the vertical motion. I think the horizontal velocity component cannot become zero, if air resistance is neglected in this direction.

Comment: The frictional force from air resistance will be directed backward from the velocity vector.

Comment: If you neglect air resistance there's no way you will ever hit the target . The projectile needs to fall vertically downward from the edge of cliff.

Comment: I did a numeric simulation for this motion (200 steps on a spreadsheet).  The projectile returns to its initial height at a horizontal distance of 94 meters in about 6.37 seconds. The horizontal velocity has dropped from 20 to 10.5 m/s, and the vertical velocity has gone from 34.6 to -28 m/s. These guys should just throw their rocks off the cliff.